# How do I get Visual Studio 2017 Installer to recognize components I have already installed separately?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017

Okay, this might be a bit silly but I'll ask anyway since I couldn't find anything relating to this on the internet (if there is, please link).

In my case, I have Python 3.6 & Unreal Engine 4 already installed on PC.

But the Visual Studio Installer automatically ticks those dependencies if try to install anything dependent on them.

What happens if I install anyway? Will I have to uninstall those first and install again through Visual Studio? Shouldn't there be a way to 'tell' the installer that I have got those components already?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the components you have installed already are missing something visual studio needs that is why it is checking it

Comment: Let it rip, tell us what you found out.

Comment: Hi Tanay Karnik, For the Unreal Engine, I suppose this issue is due to the Unreal Engine version, please check this doc: https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/VisualStudioSetup/ and it describes the Unreal Engine 4.15 or later versions are integrated with VS 2017, so VS 2017 installer want to install a higher version. For the python, please check the python under the workload Web&Cloud>Python development in the VS installer screen, from my side the options are Python 3 64/32-bit (3.6.2) and seems also higher than you installed version.